# How to automate mouse and keyboard

Tags: keyboard, automation

For UI testing I was looking for way to automate mouse movement, clicking and keyboard typing. The only thing which I have found so far is [auto clicker typer](http://www.asoftwareplus.com/auto-clicker-typer.html). It works fine, but the problem that it performs exact repetitions.

I need something that will be able to click randomly to the similar region. (If a person is clicking on the button, he does not click at the same point all the time), he clicks on the button but at random point, or even he can misses the button (if it is small).

Moreover the text, entered in the textbox is always the same. I would like to be able to check that in this region the user can enter any 1-6 digits.

I understand that may be I am asking for too much, but because this is for testing purposes, I need to be able to replicate the results. So if the program will keep track of what it was done it will be amazing.

I am using Windows, but basically platform does not matter.

Comment: [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: wow thanks. But as far as I understood from the brief reading of home page it is only for web-automation. Correct me if I am wrong, but is there anything for software automation?

Comment: For general Windows programs, I have no idea. As it's more of a programming question, you may not get a good answer here.

Comment: I already got an excellent answer in less than 10 mins from you, it's a pity it is not what I need, but still the answer is amazing. So I will hope for the best. BTW, if you will post it as an answer - I will upvote it.

Comment: This is for software testing

Comment: Then why can't the program click on the button in the same spot each time? Selenium will work... If it's a button it shouldn't matter where on the button it is clicked, it will have the same effect.

Comment: [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) might do the trick, its not actually for testing but it is very powerful tool because you can program it for apparent randomness and logging also. Its not like repeating a loop but its more of a fully programmable one.

Comment: @ekaj because may there is something next to the button, that you are clicking makes the behaviour different. Or may be if you will click button 2 times really fast - some undocumented behaviour will appear.

Comment: Is there any reasons for downvote? Bad question? Bad OP?

Comment: Might I suggest beta testers?

Comment: anything would be nice